Implementing RGB in dali system
I have a dali system in which we implemented color temperature.In that case we used #231 command for setting color temperature.
Now we want to implement RGBWAF control.
Question 1: Can I set R,g,b value directly to dali driver? If not how can I send r,g,b value to dali driver.

You need to buy the proprietary DALI protocol. It might be a copyright violation to reproduce details here.

i just want to know whether can we send r,g,b values directly

Command 249 Query Colour Type features will tell you whether RGBWAF is supported by your driver, bits 5 to 7 in the response make a number which tells you how many channels, 0 to 6 where 0 is not supported.
Command 235 Set Temporary RGB Dim level sets R, G, B values using DTR0, DTR1, DTR2 respectively.
For more details you should purchase a copy of IEC 62386-209 which is available from national standards bodies or the IEC.

I used the above commands and the color is changing but it is not working as I expected.I am sending R, G, and B values using DTR's.First I will send R value as 254,G value as zero and Blue value as zero.I expect the lights should turn on in Red color but instead it will turn ON in different color.Is there any restrictions while sending values

Power on behaviour is set with Command 45 Store DTR as Power On Level which for DT8 also copies the temporary colour type and value to the variable Power On Colour Type and Value.

What I observed is when I send R value as 254,G value as zero and B value as zero, color of light will be white.After 5 to 6 mins color will change to Red.What may be the reason?

Does it fade over 5 mins or wait 5 mins then change quickly? Anyway 5 mins is longer than the longest fade time (90s). Are you sending 226 Activate command?

it will be white color.After 5 or 6 minutes it will change to red. I am not using the 226 activate command

One more thing I observed is if I send commands 257 which is setting value to DTR0,272 which is setting device type,235 to set RGB to driver one time it wont execute.So I am sending every 10 seconds to the driver .While doing this after 5 or 6 minutes color will change. Now I changed the time to 3 seconds i.e. for every 3 seconds I will be sending commands to driver , this time it is changing 2 minutes 22 seconds to change color from white to red.

Issue solved.I stored color values in DTR0, DTR1, DTR2.Then I used command to enable the device to DT8.then used command 293 for setting RGB light.Sent dtr0 as zero.enable the device to DT8.then used command 236 again enable device type to DT8.Then sent 226.Working now
